# How to Retrieve json from server using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Json response from my server will be like this:

```
{"loginResult":"{\"Result\":2,\"UserID\":0,\"ModuleID\":1,\"ModuleName\":\"CRM\"}"}
```

Here is my service interface:

```
public interface RetrofitRest {

@POST("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{EMPLOYEECODE}/{PASSWORD}")
Call<ModelLogin>login(@Path("EMPLOYEECODE")String empcode,@Path("PASSWORD")String passwrd);
@GET("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/Msg")
Call<ModelLogin>verify(@Body ModelLogin result,@Body ModelLogin user_id);
}
```

My main activity will look like this:

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.okhttp.Interceptor;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import java.io.IOException;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Response;
import retrofit.Retrofit;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      EditText password,userName;
      Button login,resister;
      ProgressBar progressbar;
      TextView tv;
      String TAG="Fails";
      String url="http://172.16.7.203/sfAppServices/";

      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        userName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmployeeCode);

        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        userName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorfoucs);


        //progess_msz.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(nf != null && nf.isConnected()==true )
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
          showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"No Network","Please Check Your Network Connectivity",true);
        }

        final   ConnectionDetector    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String s1 = userName.getText().toString();
                String s2 = password.getText().toString();
                if (s1.equals("")) {
                    userName.setError("Enter User Name");
                }
                if (s2.equals("")) {
                    password.setError("Enter Password");

                }
                try{
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request original = chain.request();

                        // Customize the request
                        Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                .header("Authorization", "auth-token")
                                .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                .build();

                        com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                        // Customize or return the response
                        return response;
                    }
                });
                Retrofit retro = 

                 newRetrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                RetrofitRest retrofitRest = retro.create(RetrofitRest.class);

                Call<ModelLogin>call=retrofitRest.login(s1, s2);
                    String result="";
                    String userid="";
                    Call<ModelLogin> callget=retrofitRest.verify();
                    callget.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                            if(result.equals(1))
                            {
                                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter Valid Credentials",        
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                        }
                    });
              //  call.enqueue(new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
               //     @Override
               //     public void onResponse(Response<ModelLogin> response, Retrofit retrofit) {


                //        }



                //    @Override
                //    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                 //       Log.d(TAG,"Error");
                 //   }
                //});


            }catch (Exception e){
                throw e;
                }

            }
        });


     }

     public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        // Setting alert dialog icon


        // Setting OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Below code is my pojo:

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class ModelLogin
    {
    @SerializedName("Result")
    private String result;

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @SerializedName("UserID")
    private String userid;

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }


    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

My doubt is how to retrieve result and userid alone from Json string. Don't know where I am doing mistake.

Comment: simply rating down without even responding form my question

Comment: Not my downvote but I believe downvoters didn't like how you put your question. Firstly, you need to post only relevant code, not everything. Secondly, the Json response is weird, i.e string Json string inside json.

Answer (score 0):

HOW TO USE RETROFIT:

- create `POJOs` (with exactly name as your `JSON` result `KEY` or use `SerializedName` to name variables as you wish)
- create `INTERFACEs` (`GET` or `POST` depending on what actions are you willing to achieve) with `CALLBACK` parameter
- declare `CALLBACK` with `success()` and `failure()` override methods and on success you handle the response if has success, on failure you handle the fail of your call

Comment: where am doing mistake in my code can u please check it out

Comment: this is my error:  Multiple @Body method annotations found. (parameter #2)
    for method RetrofitRest.verify

Comment: try google this: Multiple @Body method annotations found. (parameter #2) for method RetrofitRest.verify

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@GET("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/Msg") 
Call<ModelLogin>verify(@Body ModelLogin result,@Body ModelLogin user_id);
}
```

use

```
@GET("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/Msg") 
Call<ModelLogin>verify(@Query("key_from_REST_API") int result,@Query("key_from_REST_API") int user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your methods in interface should be public
2. Methods should contains callback

So method in interface should look like this

```
@POST("/SF_UserLogin.svc/rest/login/{EMPLOYEECODE}/{PASSWORD}")
public void login(@Path("EMPLOYEECODE")String empcode, @Path("PASSWORD") String password, Callback<ModelLogin> callback);
```

and execute it like this:

```
retrofitRest.login(employee, pass, new Callback<ModelLogin>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ModelLogin model, Response response) {
                // success!
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                // fail
            }
        });
```

BTW
Where is ModuleName and ModuleID in your pojo?

Comment: Guy uses Retrofit 2. So methods signatures are correct.